# Does Kentico Auto-Prefix CDN Endpoint URLs to Media File Paths?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, kentico

Is anyone here familiar with using Azure or Amazon CDN services with Kentico media libraries? I have a client running Kentico v10.0.21 with Amazon CloudFront CDN in the web.config. https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/working-with-physical-files-using-the-api/configuring-file-system-providers/configuring-amazon-s3#ConfiguringAmazonS3-ConfiguringKenticotouseAmazonCloudFrontCDN

They're running into an issue where Kentico doesn't prefix the CDN Endpoint URL to media file paths. Is there any native Kentico functionality for auto-prefixing the CDN path to Media Library selections if the web.config was set up to use a CDN? I could use a custom macro to read the value from the web.config and do something with that, but it seems strange that this wouldn't be a native feature of Kentico if it already enables using CDN endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I configured a clean Kentico 10 web site to store only media files on Azure storage, (https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/working-with-physical-files-using-the-api/configuring-file-system-providers/configuring-azure-storage#ConfiguringAzurestorage-ConfiguringKenticotostoreonlymediafilesonAzurestorage). Then, I configured Kentico to use a CDN, (https://docs.kentico.com/k10/running-kentico-on-microsoft-azure/configuring-azure-cdn#ConfiguringAzureCDN-ConfiguringKenticotouseaCDN). These were not Amazon storage or CDN resources because we do not have an active Amazon Web Services (AWS) account, but they should mimic Kentico's general approach to media files and external storage providers. After completing those custom configuration tasks, I applied hotfix 10.0.21 to ensure the Kentico instance was running the same hotfix as our client.

I tested adding several media files. The media files always used an absolute URL for the direct path and relative URL for the permanent link. The direct path's absolute url always began with the CDN endpoint URL.

I tested adding media files to pages using the Rich Text widget on the page tab. The img tag's src attribute always used the direct path and always began with the CDN endpoint URL.

These tests confirm that Kentico already handles adding the CDN endpoint URL to the direct path of media files. If Kentico fails to prepend the CDN endpoint URL to the direct path of media files, then Kentico is not configured to use a CDN. If Kentico fails to prepend the cloud storage URL to the direct path of media files or uses relative URLs for the direct path of media files, then Kentico is not configured to store only media files on cloud storage.

I suspect that our client was neither configured to store media files on cloud storage nor to use a CDN.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about image URLs in a page type, then no, those have to be updated manually.  If you're talking about images in WYSIWYG editors, again no, you have to update those manually.

This is because the data is pointing to a relative path on disk and not the CDN.  So you need to update the data, which will then add the CDN information to the URL when you select an image in a page type or in your content.

Comment: Brenden, it turns out that Kentico does, in fact, prepend the CDN endpoint URL to the direct path of media files. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51991179/1671640

Comment: Your explanation in your answer though stated you configured it to store media files in Azure storage, I'm assuming this was blob storage correct?  If so then that's not the same as using "file system" storage.  I'm assuming your current setup is using relative paths in the file system storage and you want to convert it to CDN.  Correct?

Comment: Correct. The issue for this particular client ended up being that they had media libraries on both the file system and cloud storage. The redundancy caused issues where files that already exist on the local file system do not update to use the CDN. They just never removed the local media libraries when configuring their Kentico instance to store media files in cloud storage.

Comment: Nice, I was in the process of reproducing the setup you had mentioned initially and you beat me to the explanation!  So the short story is to add the CDN information but also remove physical files from the servers file system ensuring the physical files are in the CDN before deleting.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure the storage to Azure blob and endpoint URL in Web.config file like in documentation [CDN Mapping](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/running-kentico-on-microsoft-azure/configuring-azure-cdn).
Then all the new images uploaded after CDN configuration will be served with CDN endpoint.

Replace command.

For one project we have updated all the images CDN endpoints from http://ggg.net to https://yyy.net.

If you are using Staging module to sync content from stage environment to production environment then use the common CDN endpoint and common blob for both.